# How to go back a directory using php header function

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-headers

I am fairly new to PHP and I have included a script which authorises a user login, however I don't know how to go back a folder in order to access my index.html file.

I have my PHP scripts stored inside a folder so my scripts are all together however I have no way of accessing my index.html file in the previous directory. I know I can use header to redirect to a different URL but I can't redirect to index.html.

I have tried using the $_SERVER superglobal but it doesn't appear to work, any ideas?

```
if ($Count==1) {
        echo "<script 
        type='text/javascript'>alert('Welcome!') 
        </script>"; 
} else {
        echo "<script 
      type='text/javascript'>alert('Username/Password 
        incorrect!')</script>";  
        
        sleep(2);
        header('Location: INDEX.HTML IN PREVIOUS DIRECTORY');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: either use a root relative path or try using `Location: ../`in the header call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following-

```
header('Location: ../index.html');
```

Comment: nearly correct: You need to use `Location: ../index.html` ~ did not downvote though

Comment: oops.. updated.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thanks for the help everyone